# Using Twitter OAuth for automatic status update

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I want my website to automatically post status updates to a particular twitter account using OAuth in PHP.

I test this using a URL

www.mysite.com/update_status

but it asks me for "user name" and "password", which is fine when I am testing it. But my website will not be able to insert this user name and password before posting the status update.

So the question is how can a website which is in the server, automatically post a status update to an account without user filling out the user name and password.

Is there any way to bypass this? I tried saving oAuth tokens, but it's not working.

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Comment: You should elaborate on "it's not working".  Provide relevant code. Also, which (if any) Twitter library are you using?

Comment: sorry. when i say it's not working, I meant it's still asking me for "username" and "password". The website won't be able to fill the username and apssword fields. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation:

1) Use a PHP library like http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth.

2) Select your app on http://dev.twitter.com/apps and click on "My Access Token".

3) Us that access token as described on http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried this and it WORKS! And its SO SIMPLE to use!!

http://ditio.net/2010/06/07/twitter-php-oauth-update-status/

Got it working in under 5mins.

Comment: This does work great, but directions are a bit outdated.  All oAuth settings and tokens are now on your twitter apps 'details' page

Answer (score 1):

xAuth is able to do that, but Twitter only allows it for desktop and mobile apps.
In case you wanna try  it, read [this article](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2010/03/using-xauth-an-alternate-oauth-from-twitter/) and the [API docs](http://dev.twitter.com/search?query=xauth).

Comment: serious? so there is no other way?

Comment: There might be, but i'm not aware of it. A lot of people are confused about how to make the transition to OAuth. Maybe some digging on the Twitter discussion group yields a satisfying answer.

Comment: Here: http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/97889b6fc84c6d53#

Answer (score 1):

Try it with zend framework. As of version 1.10.8 minimal code required to post on Twitter is:

```
$token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access;
$token->setParams(array(
'oauth_token' => 'REPLACE_WITH_TOKEN',
'oauth_token_secret' => 'REPLACE_WITH_TOKEN_SECRET'
));

$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
'consumerSecret' => 'REPLACE_WITH_CONSUMER_SECRET',
'accessToken' => $token
));

$response = $twitter->status->update('REPLACE WITH MESSAGE');
```

All tokens and secrets can be accessed after registering your application on http://dev.twitter.com