# How can I automate the login to Twitter using Oauth?

Tags: twitter, oauth

Assumedly, I can use curl to send vars to https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate...?
All of the libraries I'm trying have the same behavior: I instantiate the object and then I'm directed to the Twitter login screen at https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate. This is not going to work for me because my users should never know the username/password for Twitter.

Comment: If I understand right, you have a single account belonging to the server/application that should post automatically.  See [
Using Twitter OAuth for automatic status update
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734272/using-twitter-oauth-for-automatic-status-update) and the article [Using one access token with OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token) from the official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used Abraham library https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth for this. Thanks.